# why the file suffix with php can't access?

Tags: linux, http-status-code-403

In my host, i created a subfolder(test) then put test.php index.php into it. when i access example.com/test   example.com/test/test.php example.com/test/index.php it all shows

```
403 Forbidden

Access to this resource on the server is denied!
Powered By LiteSpeed Web Server
LiteSpeed Technologies is not responsible for administration and contents of this web site!
```

when i created a `.htaccess` file and put it into test folder. the file(.htaccess) is empty.

```
example.com/test   example.com/test/test.php example.com/test/index.php,
```

but now, example.com/test  this url can be accessed.why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to access the mentioned file?  Just saying, it might be better to keep the index.php in the root directory of your project not in a sub directory.